# Are there any professional actors, producers, directors in here?

Tags: discussion, users

I think it would be great to identify the users who take part in movies professionally and may be able to provide great insight to how this site should work. If possible could you list your details in an answer below?

For example

> Name - optional
>   Occupation - actors/producers/directors/stage hand
>   etc...

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if I qualify as a professional (although I'm getting paid now, so maybe I am, LOL), but I do make films, I have degrees in animation and film production, I've made live-action and animated shorts that have played and won at festivals, got a couple of IMDb pages and I am now providing filmed content for a research project at the University of Waterloo.

I've done virtually every job on a film set, started out as a make-up artist, even did the catering :) Written scripts, story boarded films, even acted in one (when the real actor wasn't allowed out of his state by his parole officer - the joys of indie film).

I have a fairly extensive knowledge of film history, and the movies have always played a huge part in my life.

Oh, and my real name is Neil :)

Answer (score 8):

I did for a short time have a career in directing. (Film, TV, and Casting.)
Most of my work was semi professional and not union.

I do have experience in technical, costuming, makeup, set design, cinematography, and to a far poorer extent... writing.

I have since fled L.A. to return to Pittsburgh (The region I went to school in and studied media for both undergrad and grad).

So knowledgable, but only lightly tainted by the industry. :)

Oh, and my real name ... wait... It's in my ID. (Someone actually put up an [IMDB credit for me](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3074598/) under my professional name for an Indi-casting job.)

Comment: wot does union mean?

Comment: @Tshepang, really?

Comment: me wanna avoid guessing... lemme try: u mean u r not a member of a union? if so, what is the significance of that?