# Analysis and you, a way to improve

Tags: discussion

Our [evaluation results](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/508/evaluation-feedback-looking-forward) came back and left little to be desired in the [analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) department.

The purpose of this meta post is to ask the user base **what can we do** to encourage more Analysis content from our user base?

Should the moderators be more strict on the posts?  Should we start changing the scope of the site?  Should we require at least 5 analysis questions per user? (All *wayyyyyy* too extreme, but I think you get my point).

What would **YOU** like to see happen to encourage more analysis?

Keep in mind, the rest of the content of the site isn't going anywhere.  I would just like suggestions on ways to increase (or at least keep a nice balance of) [general trivia](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-appearance) vs [analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis).

Comment: Lack of analysis is just one woman's opinion. She may not like it, but I don't find her providing questions or answers here. Leave the members who provide the content alone!

Comment: @wbogacz It's not just her opinion, but she represents the opinion of the SE team as a whole, being an employee.  And regardless, I agree that we could use some more analysis content.

Comment: Then let them provide some analysis-heavy questions or answers to fill the gap. Sideliners can have opinions, and they're sometimes valid ones, but they could have spent their time more constructively by contributing something to site content.

Comment: @wbogacz believe me when I say the team is busy with a lot of things so I don't blame them for not providing content (though some have).  In general, the point she was trying to get across is the view of an *outsider* looking into our site.  At the end of the day, we need to provide content that not only appeases our current user base, but can attract even more users.  I'm not saying we should take what the staff says as written law, but take their criticism and see if we agree/disagree, etc. (1/2)

Comment: In the end *we* know what's best for us, and because of this post, I agree we should find a way to push for more analysis content and I am asking how (to the users) we can do that.(2/2)

Comment: I tend to agree with @wbogacz on this tbh - the feedback on the site was rather negative in my opinion.  I would love some more analysis - that is what *I* love in movies, and will continue to answer questions in that area.  We are not going to drive more activity on the site by dictating 'more of this' or 'more of that'.  I agree with the point that the numbers of engaged users are flat - hits are well up, but numbers of questions and answers are low, but I don't think we have any evidence to say that this is because we are too-trivial and not more analysis driven.

Comment: @iandotkelly Fair enough :)

Comment: I am not criticising your attempt to get more analysis going, more content is more content - its all good.  And your recent questions are excellent.  But I felt that the review of the site and the feedback appeared rather cursory.

Comment: @iandotkelly Now we just gotta get *you* to ask a question :D

Comment: Yeah I know .....  Seeing Prometheus tonight, maybe I will be inspired.

Comment: @iandotkelly For what it's worth, it's not about dictating the question types; it's about saying, "We prefer X and Y is also welcome." It's the same result, but the messaging changes the way it can be received. I may have failed in my presentation of my messaging, but I continue to believe my point was sound: this community needs to ask itself if the types of questions on the front page are going to attract/keep the users y'all want here.

Comment: @wbogacz No, myself and the team will **not** astroturf your site for you. We manage the *network* of sites, and M&TV is a member, it cannot be the sole focus of our work. Look, my job is to help guide you into making your community the place where the audience you want will be there. If you don't like my feedback, that's fine. I provided it at request in the hopes that you all could use it to improve your site. Disagree with me! That's encouraged! But *don't* follow that up by demanding that *I* personally remedy issues with your site. That's a community-of-M&TV project, not an Aarthi one.

Comment: @Aarthi - Your feedback is of course welcome, I just don't think you have any evidence to say that a certain type of content is going to attract more people.  For moving 'up-market' we tried to raise the issue of abandoning 'identify-this' and got roundly rejected.  That said, I also agree with your last point about astroturfing ....

Comment: @Aarthi - Or perhaps I should say ... if you have any evidence that going up-market (less trivia, more analysis) would grow the site then you have not shared it.  I also don't think we have any control over that, beyond encouragement - and TylerShads is making effort there.

Comment: @iandotkelly I concur that encouragement is the best option, and Tyler deserves much credit for the work he is doing. That said, it's as much about site growth as it is about audience attraction. I think the latter will lead to the former, and our observations from the network at large support this. However, as I said, my feedback is simply that: feedback. How you all choose to use it is entirely up to the mods+community. I've disagreed with some of the M&TV community decisions in the past, but I haven't fought them. I think you all will do the right thing, ultimately, whatever that choice. :)

Comment: @Aarthi.  Well if nothing else, your input and our new Topic of the Week, has sparked a few more in-depth questions again.  If we end up with a more analytical site - I for one would be happy, as long as we get traffic.

Comment: @iandotkelly One can only hope. :) I'm obviously regularly available, and I'll definitely be back for Evaluations 2: Evaluate Harder in a couple months. :D

Comment: @Aarthi Not Evaluation 2: Electric Boogaloo?

Comment: @TylerShads Many options, so few characters :D